# Pick a segment from an array of Ajax-loaded images

Tags: jquery

I need to pick and show the 3 middle images from an array of images loaded via jquery ajax

```
for (h=2;h<5;h++){
    $('#sandbox').load('./ajax/profile.html li a')[h];
        };
```

I want #sandbox to only display the three images: number 2 , 3 and 4. The code above doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the loaded html in the callback function of [**load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/),

```
$('#sandbox').load('./ajax/profile.html li a', function(result){

    $(result).find('li a:eq(1), li a:eq(2), li a:eq(3)').each(function(){
          alert(this.tagName);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks once again, how about one more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449907/ajax-loaded-images-into-elastislide-carousel

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#sandbox').load('./ajax/profile.html li a:eq(1),li a:eq(2),li a:eq(3)');
```

without the for loop

Comment: Thanks Musa, i like the simplicity too