# Ajax-loaded images into 'elastislide' carousel

Tags: jquery

Loaded images via ajax like this: Images are contained in  tags

```
$('#sandbox').load('./ajax/profile.html li a:eq(1),li a:eq(2),li a:eq(3)').hide();
```

Now i want to inject the images with their  tags into a carousel called 'elastislide'.
The code below  work, help me out!

```
for (k=0; k<=$('#sandbox').children().length;k++){
            var ajaximg = $('#sandbox').children()[k];
            var $q = $('<li>'+ajaximg+'</li> ');
            $('#carousel3').append($q);
            $('#carousel3').elastislide( 'add', $q );
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above could be corrected with the following code:

```
$('#sandbox').load('./ajax/profile.html li a', function(result){
    $(result).find('li a').each(function(){
        var $q = $('<li>').append($(this));
        $('#carousel3').append($q);
        $q.add();       
    });
});
```

The idea was to load images into the #carousel via ajax, so the code below does it all without loading to #sandbox first. It is important that the .elastislide() function be called when the document is loaded as below because thats after the images in `<li><a><img.../></a></li>` have been appended. Otherwise the carousel wont show them.

```
$('#carousel3').load('./ajax/profile.html li');
        window.onload = initStyle;
        function initStyle() {
            $( '#carousel1' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} );
            $( '#carousel2' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} );
            $( '#carousel3' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} );

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two points where you need modification IMO,

1. `var ajaximg = $('#sandbox').children()[k]` give you DOM element not jquery object you can use  `var ajaximg = $('#sandbox').children().eq(k)` instead; but its better to use `$(this)`;
2. Change var `$q = $('<li>'+ajaximg+'</li> ');`  to `var $q = $('<li>').append($(this));`

**You code  would be**

```
    for (k=0; k<=$('#sandbox').children().length;k++){
        //  var ajaximg = $('#sandbox').children()[k];
        var $q = $('<li>').append($(this));
        $('#carousel3').append($q);
        $('#carousel3').elastislide( 'add', $q );
    };
```

Comment: Thanks adil, helped me understand how the carousel works better. I have posted an answer. Your last line can easily be replaced by $q.add();